# htaccess redirect and rewrite between 2 pages

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect, url-rewriting

we have 2 pages - code.php and seo_friendly.php
seo_friendly.php is, as the name suggests, just a link with a nice name and should
actually map to code.php. this is acomplished so:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^seo_friendly.php$ /code.php [L]
```

now i'm asked that when someone navigates to code.php  (that's an old link)
they will be redirected to seo_friendly.php
i tried adding

```
redirect /code.php seo_friendly.php
```

both before and after the rewrite.
but that resulted in a loop..
any idea? thanks and have a nice day :-)

Comment: Do you have this one rule only or other rules too? If you have other rules then post your complete .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You need to match against the request itself instead of the URI (which changes as the rewrite engine is going through the rules). Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+code\.php
RewriteRule ^ /seo_friendly.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks, but now i'm getting 'Internal Server Error' when going directly to code.php.